# Need to convert psql query into typeorm

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I need to get data on daily/weekly/monthly basis. So i used date_trunc() function to get this type of record. I made psql query but i need to convert it into typeorm code as i'm new to typeorm stack. Below is the query

```
select date_trunc('day', e."createdAt") as production_to_month, count(id) as count from events e 
where e."createdAt" between '2021-05-10' and '2021-05-17' and e."type" = 'LOGIN'
group by date_trunc('day', e."createdAt") 
order by date_trunc('day', e."createdAt") asc
```

need to convert this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the query builder to achieve the desired result.

The query would be -

```
  return await getRepository(Events)
  .createQueryBuilder("e")
  .select("date_trunc('day',`e`.`createdAt`)","production_to_month")
  .addSelect("count(`id`)","count")
  .where("`e`.`createdAt` between '2021-05-10' and '2021-05-17'")
  .andWhere("`e`.`type` = 'LOGIN'")
  .groupBy("date_trunc('day',`e`.`createdAt`)").
  .orderBy("date_trunc('day',`e`.`createdAt`)","ASC")
  .printSql()
  .getRawMany()
```

Comment: Hi Soham
using this query i got data which was present at that date, for example -> 
If i've no data present at 2021-05-13, So using above query i got no row for that date, but i need that row with count present 0
Can you please help me in this

Comment: @Rochit Have you prepared an SQL query for doing the same?

Comment: I prepared the sql query, Can you please convert it into typeorm query

`SELECT sequential_dates.date, events.count
     FROM (select date_trunc('DAY', months) AS date
     from generate_series('2021-05-03' :: DATE, '2021-05-31' :: DATE, '1 DAY') as months ) sequential_dates
LEFT JOIN(
 select date_trunc('DAY', events."createdAt") AS date,
 count(events.id)  as count
 from events
 group by date
) events
on sequential_dates.date = events.date`